# travis ci test needs to run two processes

Tags: linux, bash, web-applications, parallel-processing, travis-ci

I have an web app project that has an server side and I'd like to test it using Travis-CI. On my laptop I run it like this: open two terminals, first one run server and while server is running runs my test. However I have no idea how to do that on travis, please help!

Comment: Do it the "standard" Linux-way, whatever it is. Oh, and [Google it](https://www.google.pl/search?q=linux+run+two+parallel+processes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=xf2MVqW5JOLVyAOn-pGgCA).

Comment: uh thanks, I did use Google but all I got was telling me to use && instead of & . Thanks again!